# Getting gMaps to center when opened in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am using gMaps in tabs in wordpress. I can get the map to display however when the tab is clicked, the map is not centred at its marker.

Code for gMap

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#tb_gmap_<?php echo $id; ?>").gMap({
        maptype: "<?php echo $maptype; ?>",
        zoom: <?php echo $zoom; ?>,
        markers: [
            {
                address: "<?php echo $address; ?>",
                popup: <?php echo $popup; ?>,
                html: "<?php echo $html; ?>"
            }
        ],
        controls: {
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false
        }
    });
});
```

HTML to reder the map

```
<div id="tb_gmap_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="themeblvd-gmap" style="<?php echo $styles; ?>"></div>
```

jQuery to refresh map

```
 // refresh google map
    tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/maps"], iframe[src^="http://www.google.com/maps"]').each(function(){
        this.src = this.src;
        jQuery(this).css('opacity','0');
        jQuery(this).delay(400).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
    });
    tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('.themeblvd-gmap').each(function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'resize');
            });


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
  // put this after map get refreshed

  // give marker latitude and longitude here 
  map.setCenter(latitude,longitude);
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// refresh google map
tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/maps"],  iframe[src^="http://www.google.com/maps"]').each(function () {
    this.src = this.src;
    jQuery(this).css('opacity', '0');
    jQuery(this).delay(400).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 500);
});
tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('.themeblvd-gmap').each(function () {
    var c = this.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'resize');
    this.setCenter(c);
});
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: thanks but this doesnt work as i am getting the error  `var c = this.getCenter();` is an undefined function

Comment: I would suggest you to use google maps instead of gMap. Google maps itself has same functions and options which you get in gMap. Moreover, you can easily get the documentation and help for google maps.

Comment: Well i am using google maps. its just that the jquery file is `jquery.gmap.min.js`

Comment: well google maps is in different than jquery.gmap.min.js and gMap which you used in initialisation. gMap is a separate plugin for Google Maps http://gmap.nurtext.de/

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help. I will need to use another plugin for maps for this.. thanks